# Android - Launch Fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm trying to launch a Fragment (a Listview) from an Activity.
The switch should start, when a button is clicked.

My Activity extends from Activity, the Fragment extends ListFragment.

I tried

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
AusgabenFragment ausgabenFragment = new AusgabenFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, ausgabenFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

and

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AusgabenFragment.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The error from the intent try:

> Unable to find explicit activity class

I know that I dont have to add Fragments to the AndroidManifest

Thanks for all the suggestions

EDIT: to be launched Fragment Source

```
public class AusgabenFragment extends ListFragment {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnAusgabenInteractionListener mListener;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
public static AusgabenFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AusgabenFragment fragment = new AusgabenFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public AusgabenFragment() {
}

private AusgabenDataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    dataSource = new AusgabenDataSource(getActivity()); // context mit getActivity
    try {
        dataSource.open();  // kann Exception werfen daher try catch
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<Ausgaben> AusgabenList = dataSource.getAllAusgaben();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Ausgaben>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, AusgabenList));
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnAusgabenInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AusgabenDetailsActivity.class);
    String Titel = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    intent.putExtra("value_title",Titel);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);


    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.

    }
}

public interface OnAusgabenInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onAusgabenInteraction(String id);
}
```

}

Comment: `startActivity()` is to start an activity, not to show a fragment. Please explain **completely and precisely** what problems you encountered with your first approach, which seems more likely to be correct.

Comment: Error: 'must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener'
The Debugger is in the Fragment on the Method "onAttach"

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK named `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. "The Debugger is in the Fragment on the Method "onAttach"" -- we cannot see that method, because we do not have the source for your fragment.

Comment: `@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnAusgabenInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }`

How do I post Code properly?

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK named `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. There is also nothing in the Android SDK named `OnAusgabenInteractionListener`. "How do I post Code properly?" -- there is an "edit" link under the tags, just under your question.

Comment: i edited the source to the fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnAusgabenInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

This code expects the activity that is hosting the fragment to implement `OnAusgabenInteractionListener`. It then throws an incorrect exception, to confuse you further.

If you want to use the code, your activity will need to implement `OnAusgabenInteractionListener`, whatever that is.

Comment: if I delete this passage? 
I'm working on an expense manager, after I add an expense I want to show the List-Fragment with the new added expense in the List
I dont understand why I need an InteractionListener for switching the view

Comment: @newclear: "I dont understand why I need an InteractionListener for switching the view" -- then why did you write that code? You are the one who put that code there, not I.

Comment: this passage was automatically added.
Ok I removed the passage

`Error: No view found for id for fragment AusgabenFragment`
Ok I think I need to add an ID or TAG in the xml from the called Fragment